# How start NG++ after completion of both DLC's

Tags: dark-souls-3

I have completed the game on new game plus and both dlc. I want to start a NG++  but how can I do that? I don't see the NG+ option no more at the bonfire.

Answer (score 4):

To unlock NG++ you need to defeat Lord of Cinder and chose ending. After final credits option to start new journey will be available. If you decline it there, you can later go to bonfire in Firelink Shrine and use "begin new journey" option on it.